# Duplicates generated when running threaded string builder to append csv

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a ping sweeper that pulls back basic snmp info on any valid devices in the defined ip range, and appends these results to a stringbuilder csv but i seem to get some duplicates like the first three here:

```
Date    IP  Site    MAC Manufacturer    Model   Serial
25/02/2016  10.65.10.8  CS  00:00:AA:C2:24:AC   Dell    Dell 7130cdn    XDH100611
25/02/2016  10.65.10.4  CS  00:00:AA:C2:24:AC   Dell    Dell 7130cdn    XDH100611
25/02/2016  10.65.10.3  CS  00:00:AA:C2:24:AC   Dell    Dell 7130cdn    XDH100611
25/02/2016  10.65.10.9  CS  00:00:AA:C2:3A:57   Dell    Dell 7130cdn    XDH100746
25/02/2016  10.65.10.11 CS  00:15:99:48:64:33   Dell    Dell 5330dn Mono Laser Printer  1ZG2FG1
25/02/2016  10.65.10.12 CS  00:15:99:45:93:70   Dell    Dell 5330dn Mono Laser Printer  2HC2FG1
```

it seems that as the multi threads are running sometimes the variables get updated in one thread and i end up with duplicates written to the csv. is there a better way to contain the variables to there own thread?  could i define the variables non globally? heres the sample code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var header = string.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6}{7}", "Date", "IP", "Site", "MAC", "Manufacturer","Model", "Serial", Environment.NewLine);
        csv.Append(header);

        string[] sites = { "65" };

        foreach (string site in sites)
        {
            string ipBase = "10." + site + ".10.";
            for (int i = 1; i < 255; i++)
            {
                string ip = ipBase + i.ToString();
                Ping p = new Ping();
                p.PingCompleted += new PingCompletedEventHandler(p_PingCompleted);
                countdown.AddCount();
                p.SendAsync(ip, 100, ip);
                Thread.Sleep(10);
            }
        }            
        File.WriteAllText("Printers.csv", csv.ToString());
        File.WriteAllText("Exceptions.csv", exception.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

static void p_PingCompleted(object sender, PingCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        string ip = (string)e.UserState;
        if (e.Reply != null && e.Reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
        {
            string host = ip;
            string community = "public";

            SimpleSnmp snmp = new SimpleSnmp(host, community);
            if (!snmp.Valid)
            {
                exception.Append(string.Format("{0},{1},{2}{3}", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yy"), ip, "SNMP agent host name/ip address is invalid.", Environment.NewLine));
            }
            Dictionary<Oid, AsnType> result = snmp.Get(SnmpVersion.Ver1,
                                                      new string[] { ".1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0" });
            if (result == null)
            {
                exception.Append(string.Format("{0},{1},{2}{3}", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yy"), ip, "no snmp result", Environment.NewLine));
            }
            else
            {
                    TRYONE(ip);
            }

            lock (lockObj)
            {
                upCount++;
            }
        }
    }

public static string WhatSite(string site)
    {
        string[] sitecode = site.Split('.');


        if (sitecode[1] == "65")
        {
            site = "CS";
            return site;
        }
        else
        {
            return "xx";
        }
    }

static void TRYONE (string ip)
    {
        string host = ip;
        string community = "public";
        model = "";
        serial = "";
        macaddress = "";

        SimpleSnmp snmp = new SimpleSnmp(host, community);

        if (!snmp.Valid)
        {
            exception.Append(string.Format("{0},{1},{2}{3}", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yy"), ip, "SNMP agent host name/ip address is invalid.", Environment.NewLine));
            return;
        }
        Dictionary<Oid, AsnType> result = snmp.Get(SnmpVersion.Ver1,
            new string[] { ".1.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.2.1.3.1", ".1.3.6.1.2.1.43.5.1.1.17.1", ".1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.4.3.1.23.0" });                                      



        if (result == null)
        {
                exception.Append(string.Format("{0},{1},{2}{3}", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yy"), ip, "No results received?", Environment.NewLine));
                return;
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<Oid, AsnType> kvp in result)
            {
                if (kvp.Key.ToString() == "1.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.2.1.3.1")
                {
                    model = kvp.Value.ToString();
                    if (model.Contains(";"))
                    {
                        string[] temp = model.Split(';');
                        model = temp[0];
                    }                     
                }
                if (kvp.Key.ToString() == "1.3.6.1.2.1.43.5.1.1.17.1")
                {
                    serial = kvp.Value.ToString();

                }
                if (kvp.Key.ToString() == "1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.4.3.1.23.0")
                {
                    macaddress = kvp.Value.ToString();
                    macaddress = macaddress.Replace(" ", ":");
                }

            }

            string[] manufacturer = model.Split(' ');

            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4} {5}", ip, manufacturer[0], model, serial, macaddress, WhatSite(ip));

            csv.Append(string.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6}{7}", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yy"), ip, WhatSite(ip), macaddress, manufacturer[0], model, serial, Environment.NewLine));

        }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: youmight want to read up on thread synchronization. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173179.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a better way to contain the variables to their own thread? Could I define the variables non globally?

You can define variables in the global context, but confine their use to their own thread by using [`ThreadLocal<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642243(v=vs.110).aspx).

However, in your case it appears that you are looking to combine outputs of multiple threads. One way of achieving this result is to set up a pair of global [`ConcurrentQueue<string>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265(v=vs.110).aspx) objects, one for `csv` and one for `exception`, and have the individual threads write into these queues. The main thread would then wait for the worker threads to complete, read strings from both queues one by one, and write the results to files.

Comment: Would i use the ThreadLocal<T> there the TRYONE(ip) is called, something along these lines?    `{
                    Thread.AllocateNamedDataSlot(model);
                    Thread.AllocateNamedDataSlot(serial);
                    Thread.AllocateNamedDataSlot(macaddress);

                    Thread TryOne = new Thread(new ThreadStart(TRYONE(ip)));

  //                  TRYONE(ip);

                }`

Comment: @DwayneDibbley If you decide to use named data slots for thread-local storage, you would be responsible for managing names in a way that prevents collisions. `ThreadLocal<T>` prevents collisions automatically, but it makes it harder to access thread-local data of other threads.